# Check if answer is correct from entries in database PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a user-supplied answer is correct, checking against an entry in a database.
For example: the answer is 1 and the entry in the db is "1.3 / 1.25".
using `if (strpos($correct_answer, $answer) !== false){}` returns correct because it sees the '1' in '1.3'. 
I also tried `preg_match()` which gives me the same
Would be great if someone could help :)

Comment: so you want to write a SQL query?

Comment: `1.3 / 1.25` -> what does this mean?

Comment: the correct answer is checked for every answer coming in through 'foreach' and gets the correct answer with mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh both answers are correct. 1.25 is correct but 1.3 is as well because it's rounded up

Comment: try this `if(md5($correct_answer) == md5( $answer)) { // true }`

Comment: so your problem is floating point comparison?

Comment: @AmanMaurya no not working, how did you come upo with this? md5('1') is not the same as md5('1.25 / 1.3')

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam yes I suppose so

Comment: @AmanMaurya That does not include multiple answers, that can be correct. I think the cleanest solution would be to modify your table structure and add a specific answere table. In that table there might be multiple answere rows for a singe question. Then you can fetch them and iterate the results in a loop.

Comment: Another solution would be to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) to split the string at each slash sign and iterate over each part then

Comment: @AmanMaurya yes that is one option, just tedious as there is 100+ questions with multiple possible answers each. But it is definitely a fallback option, sure

Comment: `if(in_array(1,explode('/',$answer_data)) !== false){ echo "correct";}else{echo "incorrect"};`

Answer (score 1):

Try explode: (But be aware, that this will not work for answers that contain a slash sign themself.

```
$correct_answers = explode('/', $correct_answer);

return in_array($answer, $correct_answers);
```

The best solution anway would be to create a answer table, that contains the answers and select the answers from it.

```
CREATE TABLE answer (questionid INTEGER, answer VARCHAR(255));
```

> Credits @Alive to Die--Anant singh for the in_array part.

Comment: works half the time for some reason, I think I'll have to go with the external table option, as discussed in the comments above.